# Why doesn't Clang like the __DATE__ macro?

Tags: c++, clang, qt-creator

I use the `__DATE__` macro for getting a compile-time year:

```
const QString build_year = __DATE__ + 7;
```

The Clang Code Model in QtCreator throws a `-Wdate-time` warning for using the `__DATE__` macro.

`warning: expansion of date or time macro is not reproducible`

I can disable this warning with `-Wno-date-time`, but what is wrong with using `__DATE__`?

What is an "expansion" of the macro, how can it be "reproducible" or "not reproducible", and why is "not reproducible" bad?

Comment: The builds are going to be different depending on when you build it (because the date is different).

Comment: I don't believe `clang++` enables `-Wdate-time` by default (I just tried it on my system and I don't get the warning unless I enable it explicitly). Does QtCreator enable it for you? Or make a Makefile or equivalent? You shouldn't get that warning unless something asks for it.

Comment: @KeithThompson default clang scheme in the QTCreator is "Clang-only checks for almost everything" - `-Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-unused-macros -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-global-constructors -Wno-gnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments -Wno-documentation -Wno-shadow -Wno-switch-enum -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-used-but-marked-unused`

Comment: @yalov: It's the `-Weverything` that enables `-Wdate-time`.

Comment: Actually, Clang has no opinion either way. If you pass `-Wdate-time` to the compiler then it's you who don't like `__DATE__`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Having repeated builds reproduce binary-identical outputs is desirable from many points of view. Building identical source code from identical tool chains giving different binaries each time could hide serious problems.

If you don't need to produce identical binaries every time you build identical code just disable that warning.  that's why the command-line switch exists.

Comment: Lots more reading on the subject is available at https://reproducible-builds.org/

Comment: [why reproducible builds are important](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180103-00/?p=97705#comment-1319655)

Answer (score 6):

The warning message tells you why. Using the macro does not result in a reproducible build since its value will change over time. A build in 2018 and one in 2019 will not produce the same binary.